# Timelike, spacelike etc. for higher-order tensors

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, causality

Vectors $V^\mu$ in relativity can be classified into those which are timelike, spacelike and null. A similar classification is available for tensors: A tensor 
$$T^{\mu_1\mu_2...\mu_p}_{\phantom{\mu_1\mu_2...\mu_p}\nu_1\nu_2...\nu_q}$$
Can be called timelike if $T^2<0$, spacelike if $T^2>0$ and null if $T^2=0$ where 
$$T^2=T^{\mu_1\mu_2...\mu_p}_{\phantom{\mu_1\mu_2...\mu_p}\nu_1\nu_2...\nu_q}T_{\mu_1\mu_2...\mu_p}^{\phantom{\mu_1\mu_2...\mu_p}\nu_1\nu_2...\nu_q}$$
How should we think about these notions for tensors of rank greater than one?

For vectors, there is a proper, orthochronous Lorentz transformation taking $V^\mu$ to $-V^\mu$ iff $V^\mu$ is spacelike, is this true for tensors of higher rank?

This classification is certainly useful, for instance, the existence of a frame in which the electric (magnetic) field vanishes is equivalent to the Faraday tensor being spacelike (timelike).